# Is it possible to build a lazy conditional metafunction

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, conditional-statements, short-circuiting

Suppose I want to use `std::conditional` to determine a type, if the type is a `vector<...>` the return will be a `vector<...>::size_type` and if not it will be `int`. (just an example).

A naive way to use `std::conditional`:

```
template<class V> struct is_vector : std::false_type{};
template<class T> struct is_vector<std::vector<T>> : std::true_type{};

template<class C>
using my_size_type = typename std::conditional<
    not is_vector<C>::value, 
    int, 
    C::size_type // note that this line only makes sense when condition is false
>::type;
```

However this fails because if `C` is say a `double`, `double::size_type` will give an error, even if the that is the evaluation of the second false option.

So, I am wonder if there is a sort of `lazy_conditional` in which the false (or the second false) statement is not evaluated.

I found something here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5317659/225186 but I don't know how to use it my example.

---

Note that I know how to get the same result without using `std::conditional`:

```
template<class V> struct my_size_type{typedef int type;};
template<class T> struct my_size_type<std::vector<T>>{typedef std::vector<T>::size_type type;};
```

The question is if there is a `lazy_conditional` that somehow encapsulated a `std::conditional` that is short circuited.

---

After some trial error I manage to use the ideas in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5317659/225186 and get to this that follows. It also makes me think that it is not possible to write `std::lazy_conditional` because `C::size_type` cannot appear at all in any expression a priori, so two-step expressions are needed.

```
template<class C, bool B> struct false_case{
    typedef void type;
};
template<class C> struct false_case<C, false>{
    typedef typename C::size_type type;
};

template<class C>
using size_type = typename std::conditional<
    not is_vector<C>::value, 
    int, 
    typename false_case<C, not is_vector<C>::value>::type
>::type;
```

I couldn't even condense this into a macro, because each case is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a level of indirection.

```
template<class T> struct identity { using type = T; };

template<class C> 
struct size_type_of : identity<typename C::size_type> { };

template<class C>
using size_type = typename std::conditional<not is_vector<C>::value,
                                            identity<int>,
                                            size_type_of<C>>::type::type;
```

The point is to delay looking at `C::size_type` (by instantiating `size_type_of<C>`) until you know it has one.

---

If what you really want to do is "`C::size_type` if it exists, `int` otherwise", then [`std::experimental::detected_or_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) is your friend:

```
template<class C>
using size_type_t = typename C::size_type;

template<class C>
using size_type_or_default = std::experimental::detected_or_t<int, size_type_t, C>;
```

Comment: Ok, and I guess it can't be encapsulated as a `lazy_conditional<C, T, lazy_F>`. Anyway this also shows that free metafunction are better than member (have std::size_type_of<T>::type rather than rely on T::size_type) when possible (like free function is better than member functions for generic code).

Comment: ah, this is something I discover over and over again, at the end it is the same I did here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839357/detect-operator-support-with-decltype-sfinae/18603716#18603716

Comment: On `detected_or_t` compatibility: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418570/what-compiler-option-library-do-i-need-to-use-detect-or-t-type-trait?noredirect=1#comment60486585_36418570