# What compiler option/library do I need to use detect_or_t type trait?

Tags: g++, c++14, clang++, type-traits

I am trying to use `std::experimental::detect_or_t` from `<experimental/type_traits>`.

**What compiler, option, version or library do I need to compile the following example from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected ?**

```cpp
#include <experimental/type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template<class T>
using diff_t = typename T::difference_type;

template <class Ptr>
using difference_type = std::experimental::detected_or_t<std::ptrdiff_t, diff_t, Ptr>;

struct Meow { using difference_type = int; };
struct Purr {};

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<difference_type<Meow>, int>::value, "Meow's difference_type should be int!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<difference_type<Purr>, std::ptrdiff_t>::value, "Purr's difference_type should be ptrdiff_t!");
}
```

I tried using `clang++ -std=c++14` and `g++ -std=c++14`. Also with `-std=c++1y` and `-std=c++17`. I always get this:

`main.cpp:8:44: error: 'detected_or_t' in namespace 'std::experimental' does not name a template type`

Comment: Seems to work with GCC 6. Try it on http://gcc.godbolt.org

Comment: @melak47, verified https://godbolt.org/g/1tOlXq

Comment: You can track this on Github for both [libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx) and [libstdc++](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3). It's supported in the latter, but not yet in the former.

Comment: Works with `g++ 6.3.1 -std=c++14 (c++14 is the default anyway)` and `clang++ 3.8.1 -std=c++14`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those traits were first added to libstdc++ in GCC 6.1.0, as documented in the [GCC 6 release notes](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html#libstdcxx):

> - Experimental support for most features of the second version of the Library Fundamentals TS.

And the implementation status tables in the manual, at
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.1.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#table.cxx1z_ts_status

I'm less sure about libc++, but they're not supported by the version in Clang 3.9.1 but are supported by the current trunk, so I think they first appeared in Clang 4.0.0